# Convert "Only" plain text to hyperlinks , but ignore existing hyperlinks

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, preg-replace

i need to convert plain links to hyperlinks , but only plain text to be converted , the existing hyperlinks must be skipped

the text is considered as a link if:

1. started at the beginning of the line , or a space existing before it
   i.e `(^|\s)`
2. not included inside html hyperlink or any other html tag
   i.e `[^"|']`
3. ended at the end of the line or a space exists after it

example

```
https://link1  http://link2

<-a href="http://ignored">http:-ignored<-/a>
```

the link formula is :

```
((?:https?://|ftps?://|www\.).*)
```

without consider any other options i.e just any text after http...

-- converting exists hyperlinks to plain links and re converting again is not allowed , because the text will be lost

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.*` to match links, I'd use `[^\s"\']+` that means 1 or more characters that is not a space or a quote:

```
$str = <<<EOD
https://link1  http://link2

<-a href="http://ignored">http:-ignored<-/a>
EOD;

$str = preg_replace('~(?:^|\s)((?:https?://|ftps?://|www\.)[^\s"\']+)(?:\s|$)~', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="https://link1">https://link1</a><a href="http://link2">http://link2</a>
<-a href="http://ignored">http:-ignored<-/a>
```

If you want to keep spaces that are before or after the links:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(^|\s)((?:https?://|ftps?://|www\.)[^\s"\']+)(\s|$)~', '<a href="$2">$1$2$3</a>', $str);
```

Comment: space is welcome , that is the link might has a space before it , so i don't want to ignore spaces

Comment: @SherifEldeeb: Of course it doesn't work, your regex says that url must begin with `http(s)` or `ftp(s)` or `www.`, make this group optional.